# In Django how do I get code to run after an object is saved and after its many to many relationships are made?

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have these models

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

And in my admin.py I set it so that the Group uses an inlineformset for its members relationships.

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PersonInlne]
```

When the group object is saved in the admin, I want to be able to trigger some code that would run and this code should be able to look at all of the relationships it now has after the save.  How do I go about that?

post_save signal on Group doesn't runs after Group is saved but before the m2m relationships are made and I can't get m2m_changed to work because the m2m field has a custom through attr.

Comment: Have you tried putting a receiver for `post_save` on `Membership`? Or overriding the `Group` `save()` function?

Comment: Yes, post_save on Membership will trigger for each Membership saved but I need the code to run once after all the Memberships have saved because the code will be working with all the relationships and not just each one individually.

Code inside Group's save() will always run before the m2m relationships are made since they won't happen until save is complete.

Comment: If you override the save method, you can have your code after you use super().

Comment: Unfortunately, no matter where the super is in that save function, the relationships appear to be made once the entire save() function finishes,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding `Group.save(...)` cannot work because the `Group` instance must be saved in the admin **before** the `Membership` instances are saved to ensure it exists in the database when the foreign keys are set on the memberships.

However, the Django admin provides you with a hook. You should override the `save_related` method in your `ModelAdmin` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related):

> [...] Here you can do any pre- or post-save operations for objects related to the parent. Note that at this point the parent object and its form have already been saved.

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PersonInlne]

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(GroupAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change):
        group = form.instance
        # do sth. with group and its members
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I was able to do what I wanted with save_formset() but save_related() is exactly what i was looking for.